# Rails activeadmin redirect to customized view page from customse action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have integrate active-admin in one of my rails application. Inside users edit page, I have enabled a custom action which is named as `Password reset`. When I click this action it have to take me to the custom view page which is located inside `/views/active_admin/users/password_reset.html.erb` with default **active-admin layout**.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  action_view only: :edit do
    link_to "Reset", path(id: user.id)
  end

  controller do

    def password_reset
      @user = User.find(params[id])
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  action_item :password_reset_action_item, only: :edit do
    link_to 'Reset', password_reset_admin_user_path(id: user.id)
  end

  member_action :password_reset do
    @user = User.find(params[id]) # tips: you can (& should) use `resource` to lookup records by id. it will save you a couple of lines when you integrate authorization adapters like cancancan/pundit
    render 'active_admin/users/password_reset' # you may omit this line if your template and action names are equal
  end
end
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks @Wasif Hossain

Answer (score 1):

You can user `collection_action` for this. A collection action is a controller action which operates on the collection of resources. This method adds both the action to the controller as well as generating a route for you.

```
collection_action :password_reset, method: :get do
  # Do some work here... 
end
```

and create view at `view/admin/users/password_reset.html.erb`

You can get view with default active-admin layout.

Comment: OP wants to reset password for a single user account and to achieve that, `member_action` should be the way to go instead of `collection_action`

Comment: @Pradeep Saini Thanks for your replace, I go with Hossain answer. Thanks for your time.